# How to add Event Listeners in elements created from Template Literals?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a website which has the same features like Twitter. I have a class called '.post-template' which is a div that is for every post / tweet that you create. In this div, there's a 'Comment' icon. Now the problem is I put a function on it but only the hard coded has Event Listeners. The new elements created from the Template Literals does not have event listeners / functions.

I've tried different kinds of selectors but it doesn't really work on the newly created elements from the Template Literals. I've also used the 'insertAdjacentHTML' which I thought would work but it only worked on the hard-coded text as well.

```
// This is the declaration for the comment icon
const comment = document.querySelectorAll('i.far.fa-comment');

/*
* This is the function for the Peach Button on the
* Center Bar which enables the end-user to post a
* tweet / peach and it just stacks below which is
* similar to the functionality of Twitter.
*/

peachButton2.addEventListener('click', clickPeach2);

function clickPeach2(){
    let SPValue = SPTextarea.value;
    let userIdentity = localStorage.getItem('username');
    if(SPValue !== ''){
    let sampleTemplate = `
      <!-- Post Template -->
      <div class="post-template">
          <div class="firstPart">
            <img class="profile-icon" src="your-icon.png">
          </div>
        <div class="posted-text">
           <h3>${userIdentity}</h3>
             <p>${SPValue}</p>
             <i class="far fa-comment"></i>
             <i class="fas fa-retweet"></i>
             <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
             <i class="far fa-share-square"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Post Template -->
        `;
    newsFeed.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', sampleTemplate);
        SPTextarea.value = '';
    }
    else{
        console.log('No value');
    }
}

/*
* This is function for the icons when you
* post on the center bar. It changes the
* background and adds functionality.
*/

comment.forEach(cmt => {
  cmt.addEventListener('click', () => {
    cmt.style.color = '#fff';
    cmt.style.background = '#3399FF';
  });
});

/** I expected for all the Comment Icons to work especially the new div element created from the Template Literals in Javascript. */
```

Comment: add the listener on newly created elements inside the `clickPeach2` function after you append the newly created element using `newsFeed.insertAdjacentHTML`. `comment` variable has all the comments that were available at that time, but it will not contain the newly created elements as they are not available yet when the variable is assigned using `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Why don't you use a delegate listener?

Comment: @AayushSharma Thanks for your advice! It's currently working now.